# gcc optimize cause wrong answer when using avx 512

Tags: gcc, optimization, intel, intrinsics, avx512

Update: It seems like gcc really has problem here.
I get `288 288 288` no matter what optimization options I use when compiling by clang++.
This is my code.

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdint>
#include<iostream>
#include<emmintrin.h>
#include<immintrin.h>
#include<xmmintrin.h>
using namespace std;

#define LOADU_128(addr) _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(addr))

void calc_x3(const uint8_t *ref,const int stride,const __m512i *enc)
{
    __m512i t512[9];
    for(int i(0);i!=9;++i)
        t512[i]=_mm512_setzero_si512();
    const auto stridex2(stride*2);
    auto next_line(ref+stride);
    for(int i(0),j(0);i!=6;i+=3,++j)
    {
        t512[6]=_mm512_inserti64x2(_mm512_castsi128_si512(LOADU_128(ref)),LOADU_128(next_line),1);
        t512[7]=_mm512_inserti64x2(_mm512_castsi128_si512(LOADU_128(ref+1)),LOADU_128(next_line+1),1);
        t512[8]=_mm512_inserti64x2(_mm512_castsi128_si512(LOADU_128(ref+2)),LOADU_128(next_line+2),1);
        ref+=stridex2;
        next_line+=stridex2;
        t512[6]=_mm512_inserti64x4(t512[6],_mm256_inserti64x2(_mm256_castsi128_si256(LOADU_128(ref)),LOADU_128(next_line),1),1);
        t512[7]=_mm512_inserti64x4(t512[7],_mm256_inserti64x2(_mm256_castsi128_si256(LOADU_128(ref+1)),LOADU_128(next_line+1),1),1);
        t512[8]=_mm512_inserti64x4(t512[8],_mm256_inserti64x2(_mm256_castsi128_si256(LOADU_128(ref+2)),LOADU_128(next_line+2),1),1);
        ref+=stridex2;
        next_line+=stridex2;
        t512[i+0]=_mm512_sad_epu8(t512[6],enc[j]);
        t512[i+1]=_mm512_sad_epu8(t512[7],enc[j]);
        t512[i+2]=_mm512_sad_epu8(t512[8],enc[j]);
    }
    cout<<_mm512_reduce_add_epi32(t512[3])<<endl;
    cout<<_mm512_reduce_add_epi32(t512[4])<<endl;
    cout<<_mm512_reduce_add_epi32(t512[5])<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int width(18);
    constexpr int height(8);
    uint8_t pic[width*height];
    for(int i(0);i!=height;++i)
        fill_n(pic+width*i,width,i);
    __m512i cmp[2];
    cmp[0]=_mm512_set1_epi8(0);
    cmp[1]=_mm512_set1_epi8(1);
    calc_x3(pic,width,cmp);
}
```

I get `288 288 288` when compiling by `g++ -std=c++17 -march=native main.cpp`.
But I get **`240 240`**`288` when compiling by `g++ -std=c++17 -march=native -O1 main.cpp`.
In addition, if I comment the line `t512[i+1]=_mm512_sad_epu8(t512[7],enc[j]);`, I will get `240 0`**`240`** when compiling by O1 flag. (why does the third answer change to **240**???)
Does gcc have some problem here? Or it is my problem?
BTW, If you have a good title for this problem, please let me know.
Below is my machine information.
CPU i7-7820X
gcc version 7.3.1 20180312 (GCC)
clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final) Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Linux 4.15.14-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT

Comment: You'd have to look at the asm output to find out exactly why / how gcc is miscompiling your code.  I don't see any obvious undefined behaviour, like unsafe pointer-casting that would make it valid for the compiler to produce different behaviour at different optimization levels.  (Because UB means *anything* can happen.)

Comment: I think you've done enough testing (and have a short enough [mcve]) to warrant filing this as a gcc bug, not a SO question.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/.  That's where gcc devs can see it and look at the GIMPLE / RTL and figure out what happened.